# Calling a method for a class created in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, methods

http://jsfiddle.net/3BqtV/
Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){            
        $("#first").click(function(){
            $("#secondHolder p").addClass('red');
            });
        $(".red").click(function(){
            $(this).css("color","red");
            });
})
```

HTML:

```
  <p id= "first">Click me first to give Second the class "red"</p>
  <div id= "secondHolder"><p>Click on first, then click on me, and I should be red.</p>     </div>
```

Basically, when one element is clicked, I want to add a class to another element. And then, I call a method on the click function of the new class and have it change color to red. 
Sorry if it's a basic question, I'm kinda new to javascript. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.click`, use `.live('click'` - it matches any element with that selector now, or at any future point.

http://jsfiddle.net/3BqtV/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){            
        $("#first").click(function(){
            $("#secondHolder p").addClass('red');
            });
        $(".red").live('click', function(){
            $(this).css("color","red");
            });
})
```